# Condition to toggle a set of divs based on dropdown and radio selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Condition to toggle a set of divs based on dropdown and radio selection

I need a way to toggle a set of divs based on the selection of a dropdown 
AND if a radio button is selected. It would be a toggle and not two 
separate div instances

Dropdown = If 1 = Show div1, If 2 = Show div2, If 3 = Show div3, If 4 = Show div4

If "subscription" radio is selected then the dropdown would toggle 4 different divs and hide the previous ones - 
Dropdown = If 1 = Show div5, If 2 = Show div6, If 3 = Show div7, If 4 = Show div8

```
<Select id="dropdown">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
<option value="4">Four</option>
</Select>
<input type="radio" name="subscription" id="subscription" value="">

<!-- If subscription is NOT selected, dropdown toggles these -->
<div id="div1">Some content aaa</div>
<div id="div2" style="display: none">Some content bbb</div>
<div id="div3" style="display: none">Some content ccc</div>
<div id="div4" style="display: none">Some content ddd</div>

<!--If subscription IS selected, dropdown toggles these -->
<div id="div5" style="display: none">Some content fff</div>
<div id="div6" style="display: none">Some content ggg</div>
<div id="div7" style="display: none">Some content hhh</div>
<div id="div8" style="display: none">Some content iii</div>
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're having trouble with and what your specific question is. You can start withe a Google search on "jQuery click event" and "jQuery show/hide element".

Comment: @Nicolas Yes, I tried the first few answers. One worked but stacked the divs instead of replacing and the jQuery switch option makes the most sense but didn't work (see below)
https://jsfiddle.net/mjm86/wf1jqu43/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses JQuery:

```
$("#dropdown").on("change", toggleDivs());


function toggleDivs() {

    hideAllDivs();

    var dropdownSelected = $("#dropdown").find("option:selected").val();
    var isSubscription = $("input[name='subscription']:checked");

    switch(dropdownSelected) {

        case "1": 
            if(!isSubscription) {
                $("#div1").toggle();
            }
            else {
                $("#div5").toggle();
            }

            break;

        case "2": 
            if(!isSubscription) {
                $("#div2").toggle();
            }
            else {
                $("#div6").toggle();
            }

            break;

        case "3":
            if(!isSubscription) {
                $("#div3").toggle();
            }
            else {
                $("#div7").toggle();
            }

            break;

        case "4": 
            if(!isSubscription) {
                $("#div4").toggle();
            }
            else {
                $("#div8").toggle();
            }

            break;
    }
}


function hideAllDivs() {

    $("div").css("display", "none");
}
```

The idea here is: when the dropdown changes value fire the `toggleDivs()` function.

In `toggleDivs()`, first hide all divs to have a sort of reset.  Then, get the value of the dropdown option selected, as well as if the 'subscription' radio button was checked.  In the switch case, that is where you will toggle the appropriate div according to the requirements.  E.g.: if the dropdown selected was '1', display 'div1', unless the 'subscription' radio button was checked, then show 'div5', etc.

Comment: In theory this makes sense and is what I'm looking for however it doesn't seem to be working. 
https://jsfiddle.net/mjm86/wf1jqu43/1/

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned that since this uses jquery, you need to include it in your project if you haven't already.  Here is a working version (with some updated syntax): https://jsfiddle.net/kplump1395/ca5hj7ru/1/

Answer (score 1):

simply add a class to tell groups appart

```html
<Select id="dropdown">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
</Select>
<input type="radio" name="subscription" id="subscription" value="">

<!-- If subscription is NOT selected, dropdown toggles these -->
<div><strong>NOT</strong> subscription</div>
<div id="div1" class="to-toggle not-subscription" style="display: none">1 Some content bbb</div>
<div id="div2" class="to-toggle not-subscription" style="display: none">2 Some content ccc</div>
<div id="div3" class="to-toggle not-subscription" style="display: none">3 Some content ddd</div>
<div id="div4" class="to-toggle not-subscription" style="display: none">4 Some content ddd</div>

<!--If subscription IS selected, dropdown toggles these -->
<div>Subscription</div>
<div id="div1" class="to-toggle subscription" style="display: none">1 Some content fff</div>
<div id="div2" class="to-toggle subscription" style="display: none">2 Some content ggg</div>
<div id="div3" class="to-toggle subscription" style="display: none">3 Some content hhh</div>
<div id="div4" class="to-toggle subscription" style="display: none">4 Some content iii</div>
```

```
const select = document.querySelector('#dropdown')
const subscription = document.querySelector('#subscription')

select.addEventListener('change', e => {
  // hide all divs
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.to-toggle')
  for(let div of divs){
    div.style.display = 'none'
  }
  // check if radio is checked, then affect desired div
  if (subscription.checked) {
    document.querySelector(`#div${e.target.value}.subscription`).style.display = 'block'
  } else {
    document.querySelector(`#div${e.target.value}.not-subscription`).style.display =
      'block'
  }
})
```

**see demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p7zby84m/)**

Comment: Great thanks! This is really close but I need the divs to toggle so only one is shown at a time. So if dropdown three is selected it shows "3 Some content ddd" but once the radio is clicked it switches to "4 Some content iii". If the radio was unchecked it would revert back

Comment: Then to achieve that, you could loop through all the divs and set them `display = none` to all and then do the check to show the one selected

Answer (score 0):

This uses plain JavaScript:

```
let displayedDiv = document.getElementById("div1");
function onChange(){
   displayedDiv.style.display = "none"

  let dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
  let value = dropdown.value
  let radioCheck = 
    document.getElementById("subscription").checked;
  if(radioCheck){
      displayedDiv = document.getElementById(`div${parseInt(value) + 4}`)
  } else {
      displayedDiv = document.getElementById(`div${value}`)
  }
  displayedDiv.style.display = "block"
}
```

Attached the function to an onchange property to both the select element and input element.

This assumes you have exactly eight divs, otherwise, it would make more sense to have div1 be dropdown = 1, radio = 0, and div2 be dropdown = 1, radio = 1, etc. That way you can just multiply the value by 2.